# Multiple JOIN with JPA

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have 3 entity Group with Student (1 - ∞) and Ratings in Students (1 - ∞) 
**Group**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "`group`")
public class Group implements Serializable {
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_group")
    private List<Student> students;
}
```

**Student**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "student")
public class Student implements Serializable {
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL,fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_student")
    public List<Rating> ratings;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_group")
    private Group group;
}
```

**Rating**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "rating")
public class Rating implements Serializable {
    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    @Column
    private Date date;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_student")
    public Student student;
}
```

My goal is to select all grop by id with students with student ratings between  2 dates.
Solutions that I tried

```
 @Query(value = "select g from Group g INNER JOIN g.students s ON g.id = :id INNER JOIN s.ratings r ON r.student.id = s.id and r.date between :dateStart and :dateEnd GROUP BY g.id")

 @Query(value = "SELECT * FROM Group g INNER JOIN student ON g.id_group = :id RIGHT JOIN rating on student.id_student = rating.id_student and rating.`date` between :dateStart and :dateEnd GROUP BY g.id_group",nativeQuery = true)

 @Query(value = "select g from Group g WHERE g.id = :id and g.students IN (select s from g.students s JOIN s.ratings r where r.date between :dateStart and :dateEnd) GROUP BY g.id")
```

Comment: Where is the question?

Comment: place the `Rating` class too.

Comment: @MohsenR.Aqdam added

Comment: @AndrianekenaMoise the question goes from my goal and solution that I tried. If you wanna me to duplicate it, I will do.

Answer (score 0):

Your @OneToMany mapping is wrong. Use `@OneToMany(mappedBy="ratings")` instead of @JoinColumn. See https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/OneToMany#Example_of_a_OneToMany_relationship_and_inverse_ManyToOne_annotations

In JPQL no need to join with ON condition. JPA will do it automatically based on foreign key:

```
select g from Group g 
JOIN g.students s 
JOIN s.ratings r 
WHERE  g.id = :id 
AND r.date between :dateStart and :dateEnd
```